# How to remove empty object tags

Tags: json, jsonata

Given the following JSON:

```
{
      "identifers": {
        "_id": "f073895e207c3157",
        "attrsDigest": "-706912700",
        "entityTypes": [
          {
            "_id": "bacf9e903a6c5def",
            "attrsDigest": "1537152651"
          },
          {
            "_id": "08aac63dacd579c8",
            "attrsDigest": "-1461027456"
          }
        ],
        "statuses": [
          {
            "_id": "50912252d4781056",
            "attrsDigest": "154590869"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I need to produce the following:

```
{
  "identifers": [
    {
      "_id": "f073895e207c3157",
      "attrsDigest": "-706912700"
    },
    {
        "_id": "bacf9e903a6c5def",
        "attrsDigest": "1537152651"
    },
    {
      "_id": "08aac63dacd579c8",
      "attrsDigest": "-1461027456"
    },
    {
      "_id": "50912252d4781056",
      "attrsDigest": "154590869"
    }
    ]
  }
```

I've got the following:

```
[**].${ "identifers": _id, "digest": attrsDigest }
```

which produces this:

```
{
  "identifers": [
    "f073895e207c3157",
    "bacf9e903a6c5def",
    "08aac63dacd579c8",
    "50912252d4781056"
  ],
  "digest": [
    "-706912700",
    "1537152651",
    "-1461027456",
    "154590869"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ["reduce" operator](https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators#---reduce) to group your nested data by ID and then format it into an array of the desired shape:

```
**{ _id: attrsDigest }
  ~> $each(function($attrsDigest, $id) {
    { "_id": $id, "attrsDigest": $attrsDigest }
  })
```

Live playground: https://stedi.link/A1yo9Pz